# VBA run-time error 1004 The maximum number of data series per chart is 255

Tags: vba, charts

I just started learning VBA in school. We have to make a chartsheet that is created in a subroutine, and this subroutined is called in the main subroutine. At first my code worked fine, but after running the code several times I got error 1004  he maximum number of data series per chart is 255. I did not change anything in the code, as soon as I just run the code a few times I got this error, even when it previously worked with the exact same input. And now I keep getting it. Thank for your help.
Code is below:

```
Call chartSimulatedPrices(userETF, noweeks)

Public Sub chartSimulatedPrices(userETF, noweeks)

Dim yLow As Double
Dim yHigh As Double
Dim myChart As Chart
Dim pricesDataRange As Range

Sheets("Simulated Prices").Activate
yLow = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(noweeks, 17)))
yHigh = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(noweeks, 17)))

Set pricesDataRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(noweeks, 17))
Set myChart = Charts.Add


ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=pricesDataRange
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Simulated Prices for " & userETF

'Everything mentioned below is formatting

'Switch axes so that Weeks are shown on the x axis and Prices are shown on _ the y axis
ActiveChart.PlotBy = xlColumns

'Format y axis (use xlValue)
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = yLow
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = yHigh


'Format graph using Macro
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Position = xlBottom

'Remove "week" from the legend and graph
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(1).Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
Selection.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Selecting your range before Charts.Add in case it's picking up an already selected range for the chart

Comment: I get another error in that case:  Run time error 91 Object Variable or 
With Block variable not set.  It highlights the first line of the following code:
'ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=pricesDataRange'
 'Set myChart = Charts.Add'

Comment: What have you changed in your code, it looks like from what you've posted that you're now trying to set the chart data before you've created the chart.

Create the range
Select the range
Create the chart
Set the chart source data.

Comment: Isn't that what I do in the code in my original post? "Create  and select the range" is "Set pricesDataRange", then I create the chart "Set myChart=charts.add" and then I set the source data.

Answer (score 0):

Typing Activecells before the charts.add part fixed the issue.

Updated code:

```
Call chartSimulatedPrices(userETF, noweeks)

Public Sub chartSimulatedPrices(userETF, noweeks)

Dim yLow As Double
Dim yHigh As Double
Dim myChart As Chart
Dim pricesDataRange As Range

Sheets("Simulated Prices").Activate
yLow = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(noweeks, 17)))
yHigh = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(noweeks, 17)))

Set pricesDataRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(noweeks, 17))
Activecells(1,1).Select
Set myChart = Charts.Add
```